# Fluent setter returning null value on a factory - PHP

Tags: php, symfony, factory, setter, fluent

In a Symfony project I have created the Factory below :

```
<?php

namespace Company\MyBundle\Factory;

use Company\MyBundle\Entity\ParentRequest;
use Company\MyBundle\Entity\ChildRequest;
use Company\MyBundle\Entity\Foo;
use Company\MyBundle\Entity\Bar;

/**
 * Class ChildRequestFactory
 *
 * Factory instanciating  ChildRequest with several values
 * @package Company\MyBundle\Factory
 */
class ChildRequestFactory extends AbstractRequestFactory
{

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @param Bar|null $bar
     * @param Foo|null $foo
     * @return ChildRequest
     */
    public function createRequest(\DateTime $date, Bar $bar 
= null, Foo $foo = null)
    {
        $childRequest = new ChildRequest();
        $childRequest
            ->setDateValidation($date)
            ->setIsValid(ParentRequest::IS_VALIDATED)
            ->setFoo($foo)
            ->setBar($bar)
            ->setBaz('baz')
            ->setOrigin('Manager')
        ;

        return $childRequest;
    }
```

This factory is used by **Service** used by a Symfony **command**.
Let's explain the problem right now :

- When executing the command in local dev environment with dev fixtures, the factory correctly create and return the object.
- When executing the command in local dev environment with preprod database, the factory correctly create and return the object.
- When executing the command in preprod environment using preprod database, the following error is raised :

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setFoo() on null in /var/www/application/src/Company/MyBundle/Factory/ChildRequestFactory.php on line 37**

**[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Error: Call to a member function setFoo() on null**

**Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/application/src/Company/MyBundle/Factory/ChildRequestFactory.php:37**

This error only appears on the preprod environment.
I have already check the versionning, the code is on the same git branch on the local and the preprod environments.
The cache has already been remove in preprod.
Database sync/schema update : OK

Symfony version : **2.7.13** (local and preprod)
PHP version : **5.6.17** (local) / **5.6.23** (preprod)

When I don't use the fluent setters it's solve the problem on preprod env.

Any idea ?

Notice : I have changed the name of the bundle and some variables/classes/methods for confidentiality.

**Update :**

This is the setIsValid setter returning null.

```
/**
 * Set is_valid
 *
 * @param integer $isValid
 */
public function setIsValid($isValid)
{
    $this->isValid = $isValid;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: show us your `setIsValid` method

Comment: my bet is that there's something wrong with `ParentRequest::IS_VALIDATED` - some autoload issue or something similar but it's hard to tell for sure. Can you try to change it to a concrete value and see if this works?

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski It doesn't work when passing concrete value like 1. Same issue

Comment: The only possible reason is that the `return $this;` is not reached, possibly by an exception raised or an error beforehand

Comment: @GhostCat my mistake. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You are very welcome. Thank you for your kind comeback! Nice question and self answer btw!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the origin of the problem. I usually do operations like rebases, interactive rebases or bisects with command line but I use GitKraken for simple commits and pushs. I suppose there was some issues using it because the changes including making all setters fluent was not pushed to the preprod environment. What a shame I didn't see it...all the new changes were present in the preprod environment except these one. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `setIsValid` don't return `$this` ot another object ?

Comment: I have already check this issue. All the setters return $this...and why it doesn't work only on preprod environment with the same data fixtures ?

Comment: I can't answer without code. Maybe you have some condition in that setter and returning null/void. Or you override class and child (or parent) return null.